# Excepción Hibernate con JPA compilar proyecto

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Buen día. Estoy realizando prácticas con eclipse-hibernte y JPA, pero no he podido culminarla, puesto que sale el siguiente excepción al ejecutar la app:

> INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
> ago 05, 2020 2:21:47 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections 
> INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
> ago 05, 2020 2:21:47 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator initiateService
> WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Unable to resolve name [MySQLDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

Mi archivo persistence.xml es asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La estructura proyecto está asi:

[image: Estructura proyecto eclipse]

También probé la conexión de manera típica (jdbc)y logró conectarse.

AGRADEZCO MUUCHO QUIEN PUEDA ORIENTARME.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error indica:

> Unable to resolve name [MySQLDialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]

Debes seleccionar el dialecto correcto con el que hibernate debe trabajar, coloca MySQL5Dialect si tu versión de hibernate es la última sino debes buscar acá la que corresponda: [Dialectos de hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html)

Comment: efectivamente era dialecto, lo reemplace por org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect, luego solicitó ajustar timeZone y funcionó. Mil mil gracias